# Mysql запросы, вывести минимальное и максимальное значение

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица бд такого вида -

```
id  type
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   1
5   1
6   1
```

Какой запрос к бд отправлять, чтобы в ответ получить 2 последние записи со значением type 0 и 2 последние записи со значением type 1?

Comment: Понятие "последние" не существует, пока не указана сортировка, при которой все  записи уникальны.

Comment: Можно по наибольшему значению id выводить, как мне кажется...